# Problem with SSL after update to Jooma 3.4.1

Tags: ssl

Since the update to 3.4.1. I have problems with SSL redirection. The base url of images en css is not redirected to https so the pages won't load anymore. I can't find anything about this on google.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think I remember a very similar (if not, the same) question asked a few months ago. I'll try and dig it up for you. In the mean time, can you look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986572/ssl-issue-in-joomla-web-site

Comment: Found it, but unfortunately the question was closed. The OP said this was the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986572/ssl-issue-in-joomla-web-site

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things you can try:

- Check the `$live_site` variable in your `configuration.php` file to see if it has a reference to an non-https url.
- Check if your `.htaccess` file has some custom rewrite rules that covers CSS files and images.
- Look at the source code of your live site and see how the URL is generated.

If you want to develop your own plugin, you should take a look at the following site: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

Comment: Thank you!! :-) $live_site had a http:// but.... we didn't have problems with the site earlier. I think it happend after updating to 3.4.1. When $live_site is set to https is that not a problem for the pages that do not use ssl? And shouldn't Joomla change the base utl itself when a page has to be loaded in https?

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/change-http-to-https-in-source-code-when-using-ssl) some time ago. My problem was that some of the files were referenced using an absolute URL in the source code (beginning with `http://`. If that's the case with your site, the solution is to replace `http://` with simply `//`. I ended up doing it manually, but David Fritsch suggested a small plugin to take care of this:

```
public function onAfterRender() {
    $buffer = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();
    $pattern = '~<[^>]*["\']\Khttps?://~i';
    $replacement = '//';
    $buffer = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $buffer);
    JResponse::setBody($buffer);
}
```

Comment: I read this post, but I don't know how to make a plugin for this? And there is no http:// in my template, it's all with the code : '<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>', images files are on the server and placed with JCE.